# Selenium WebDriver - session is lost during the test on submit randomly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I am currently trying to solve a problem which occurs during the tests randomly. First I'll try to describe the problem, than I'll try to describe my environment and tools. Since many tools are involved, I am just asking for general ideas for why could such a behaviour occur.

**Problem:**

I have multiple suits of tests with forms etc., during which the user is suddently signed out when he submits a form - I can see that there is different jsessionid before the submit and after in the log but it happens totally randomly. Sometimes the test succeeds, sometimes I have the same form with multiple variations of how it can be filled and it happens randomly upon any of the variations. **I am killing all the IE processes and IEDriver processes between the suits and at the start** to ensure that there are not multiple IE opened.

**Environment:**

I am using **Selenese Runner** (can run tests in HTML format in any browser - works like a proxy over the webdriver) to run the tests with **IEDriverServer** (32-bit, 2.53). Tests are beying run automatically by the **jenkins** on it's slave (started using JWS) - **RDC** is used to connect to slave before test to ensure GUI is fine. Slave is a virtual server (Windows Server 2008 R2 enterprise). Tests are run on **IE10**, **protected mode is disabled on all zones**. Tested pages uses NTLM authentification. IEDriver is run with the following capabilities:

```
    caps.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
    caps.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
    caps.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
    caps.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
```

Currently I have no idea what could be possibly wrong and any help will be really appreciated.

**EDIT - hopefully better description of a problem:**
I have 3 suits where every suit contains 7 tests on average. During those tests, some workflow is tested - for example search for a client, edit his attributes, show them, export them etc. During those tests sometimes user is suddently logged out - for eample instead of getting on a detail page, login page is shown, instead of creating new client (form submit), login page is shown etc - caused by clickAndWait command. I can see in the log, that the jsessionid has been changed (before and after the clickAndWait command) but I don't know why. This sudden log out occurs randomly - for example I have a test, where there is page A with search form, page B with results and page C with detail. Sometimes test succeeds, sometimes user is logged out when clicking on the detail link on page B, sometimes he is logged on on search form on page A. Tests itself are good and if I run them locally, they work. I hope that now it's more clear what the problem is.

Comment: It's not quite understandable what action you expect from your tests and what is actual one. Also tell us please why you connect your issue with Jenkins. Could it be that you've written wrong tests?

Comment: I have added better explanation of a problem (hopefully), jenkins is connected because tests are failing on jenkins slave so it could have some connection.

Comment: Okay please show also what clickAndWait is. How do you implement it?

Comment: Is is impleneted as a click on WebElement class:
WebElement element = finder.findElement(driver, locator);
element.click();

Comment: Have you tried to find a trigger? Maybe it happens after some timeout? Are you sure you run tests on your local machine with the same input data? My point is the problem is not in Jenkins.

Comment: I also think that jenkins isn't the cause, I just wanted to give all relevant data about the environment in which the tests are beying executed. For example the way jenkins slaves are started may affect the tests, because of missing GUI - causing black screenshots etc, so I mentioned jenkins to be sure all relevant data for possible solution are here. The most probable cause will be something with IE settings, OS settings, security settings or so...but I don't know and can't figure it out.